# Using the keyword this vs NOT using this in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, constructor, scope, this

So I came across a really strange behavior I cannot seem to find the answer to.

I understand how the keyword `this` is being used in `this.score.push(newscore)` in the `addScore` method; `this` refers to the specific object that was created. In this case, `this` is referring to the student object stored in the variable `billy`.

However, let's say I remove `this` so the `addScore` method reads `score.push(newscore)`. Okay, I know this will work as well since `score` is now referring to the initial input of the new student object creation: `[80,90,100]`. The scope of `score` should allow this as well.

What really boggles me is when I call `billy.score` to view his scores, the new score that has been added by the `addScore` method is there, saved and stored! How in the world can the new score be stored like so if the `score` is only referring to the input? Shouldn't the new score **not** be stored in the `score` array since it was added to an input and not the property of the object ie. `this.score`?

Thanks so much in advance for reading and I hope to discuss this with you all!

```
function Student(name, score){
  this.name = name;
  this.score = score;
  this.addScore = function(newscore){
    this.score.push(newscore) // vs score.push(newscore)
  }
}

var billy = new Student("Billy", [80,90,100]);
```

Comment: `this.score` and `score` are both the same array. Arrays are objects, and reference values as such, the assignment `this.score = score;` copies only the reference from the variable to the property but did not create a copy of the array.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks Bergi for the answer. I understand that `this.score` and `score` are the same array. However, I never save the input array `score` in a variable. Does the input `score` get instantiated as an instance variable for the particular object in JavaScript?

If I delete the whole line of `this.score = score`, the constructor function still works when you `addScore` without pushing the new score into `this.score`.

Comment: The parameter `score` *is* a variable. A variable that is available in the constructor scope and that will be preserved through the `.addScore` closure.